# How can I run JIRA on Windows via a subdomain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-host, subdomain, jira

I am looking around the JIRA documentation but I cannot find any information on this, but perhaps I'm not searching for the right terms :(

I've heard something about the concept of `VirtualHost`s in the Confluence documentation but I don't really know where to start; I'm traditionally a .NET developer =)

My JIRA is up and running, i am aware of the xml configuration files in the `JIRA\conf` directory and can edit what is required.

I have pointed http://jira.mydomain.com to our public IP and am ready to go. It's currently running on http://localhost:8085.

**Update: This question is 6 days old and would really love some help, anyone? :|**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone wants to know, the best method I found was to use the Tomcat IIS Connector via JIRA's wiki documentation on [Integrating JIRA with IIS](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+IIS).

This allows you to run on a /jira sub directory, or http://jira.domain.com sub-domain/virtual host if you so wish.

Utilising a sub-domain is not detailed in the wiki, only getting IIS to proxy requests to Tomcat through a sub-directory, so if you wish to use a sub-domain, follow the instructions as per normal but observing the following tips:

1. *This is a general point* - Ensure on the IIS Site you are told to create, the binding is mapped to port `80` with a host header of `jira.yourdomain.com`.
2. In your `JIRA\conf\server.xml` file leave the path empty for the `<Context path=""...>` attribute where the wiki documentation tells you to specify one. Only enter one such as `/jira` for eg. if you are using sub-directories.
3. Ensure your `JIRA\conf\server.xml` file `port` attribute of the `<Connector...>` element is set to something other than `80` which IIS will be running on. For instance the default I believe installs to `8080` so leave it at that.
4. Lastly, in your `tomcat_iis_connector\conf\uriworkermap.properties` folder used for the ISAPI proxy filter, make sure your worker entry is listed as: `/*=worker1` and not `/jira/*=worker1` which the documentation suggests you do.

That should be it, now run an `iisreset` and reboot of your JIRA service and you're good to go. Can't believe this isn't really detailed on the net or the sub-domain option wasn't detailed in the Atlassian Wiki. Perhaps it's simple to those familiar with Tomcat, I'm not sure!

Best of luck and hope you don't have the headache I had!

Comment: You also get to skip the step "Create a virtual directory for JIRA in IIS" (before the step to create the /jakarta virtual directory).

Comment: Hi people. Greate answer. Thanks author for this. Spent 1 day to resolve this anyway so share - if you have router or other network devices which can block your 80 port be sure to allow this port and/or redirect to IIS server. Regards, Andrew

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to leave IIS completely out of the loop for this. For this to work, you need to assign additional IPs to your machine. Then you will make IIS listen to one IP and JIRA/Tomcat to another, which you then can simply create a DNS entry for.

By default, IIS will listen to port 80 (HTTP) on all IPs assigned to the server. Obviously, Tomcat and IIS can not both handle the same IP on the same port, so you will have to tell IIS which IPs it should handle and do the same for Tomcat.

For IIS you do it like this:

- Open command prompt
- Type netsh
- Type http
- Type sho iplisten; result should be blank
- Type add iplisten ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; repeat this for all IP addresses used by websites hosted on IIS
- Type sho iplisten again to verify
- Iisreset

(taken from the first comment [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+IIS#IntegratingJIRAwithIIS-jiraandconfluencewithiis))

Then you have to assign the IP you want to use for JIRA in the Tomcat config file. This should be located at **[JIRA install dir]\conf\server.xml**:

Change the following entry

```
<Connector port="8080" ...
```

to

```
<Connector port="80" address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ...
```

For the address you insert the one you want JIRA to use.

Hint: If you have trouble connecting to this IP through the browser, make sure you have the firewall configured correctly to allow incoming connections on port 80 for this IP address.

Now you simply create a DNS record pointing your subdomain *jira.yourdomain.com* to the IP assigned for Tomcat/JIRA and you are good to go.

You can do the same for a parallel Confluence installation, you just have to assign an additional IP for each setup.

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment what your problem is.